# Why doesn't this function finish its calculation?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm writing a function that receives a matrix with the work shifts for each employee in a day and returns a matrix that contains how many people work each hour of the day. Each work shift looks like this: '07:00-15:00'. The problem is that the program doesn't return a result and runs indefinably. This is the code:

```
def count_workhours(data):
    work_hours =  [0] * 24
    for row in workshifts:
        start, end = row.split('-')
        start_hour, start_minute = start.split(':')
        end_hour, end_minute = end.split(':')
        if end_hour>start_hour:
            while(start_hour<end_hour):
                work_hours[int(start_hour) - 2] += 1
        elif end_hour==0:
            workshifts.append(24+int(end_hour))                
            while(start_hour<end_hour):
                work_hours[int(start_hour) - 2] += 1

    return np.array(work_hours)
```

Comment: In your `while(start_hour<end_hour):`loops, you never update neither `start_hour` nor `end_hour`, so there is no way to exit the loop.

Comment: this code seems extremely fragile. where are `workshifts` defined? why aren't you using datetime library and opting to roll your own time manipulation? this feels like an X Y problem where you actually want to do X, but are asking about Y. what are the inputs and desired outputs for your function?